# how to get json data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am generating radio button depends on jsondata id and name. but below code is not working.how to resove this issue.

Json:

```
{
    "a": [
            { "id" : "a1", "family" : "Family" },
            { "id" : "a2", "family" : "Family" },
            { "id" : "a3", "family" : "Family" }
        ],
    "b": [
            { "id" : "b1", "family" : "Family" },
            { "id" : "b2", "family" : "Family" },
            { "id" : "b3", "family" : "Family" }
        ],
    "c": [
            { "id" : "c1", "family" : "Family" },
            { "id" : "c2", "family" : "Family" },
            { "id" : "c3", "family" : "Family" }
        ]
}
```

Javascript:

```
generateFamily("a");

function generateFamily(objt) {
    var Objct = objt;
    $.getJSON("./js/result.json", function(result) {
        var testobj = result + "." + Objct;
        $.each(testobj, function(i, field) {
            var char = "a";
            char = "ln-" + char;
            $("#dFour").append("<li class=" + char + " style='display: list-item;'><a href='#'><span class='m'><input type='radio' class='fbol_ff' value=" + field.id + " family=" + field.family + "/></span>" + field.family + "</a></li>");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the error showing in the console?

Answer (score 2):

You nee to read the `a` field from JSON data. Since you are passing `a` in a variable i.e. `objt`. You can fetch that using [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
var testobj=result[objt];
```

instead of

```
var testobj = result + "." + Objct;
```

```js
var result = {
  "a": [{
    "id": "a1",
    "family": "Family"
  }, {
    "id": "a2",
    "family": "Family"
  }, {
    "id": "a3",
    "family": "Family"
  }],
  "b": [{
    "id": "b1",
    "family": "Family"
  }, {
    "id": "b2",
    "family": "Family"
  }, {
    "id": "b3",
    "family": "Family"
  }],
  "c": [{
    "id": "c1",
    "family": "Family"
  }, {
    "id": "c2",
    "family": "Family"
  }, {
    "id": "c3",
    "family": "Family"
  }]
};


generateFamily("a");

function generateFamily(objt) {
  var testobj = result[objt];
  $.each(testobj, function(i, field) {
    var char = "a";
    char = "ln-" + char;
    $("#dFour").append("<li class=" + char + " style='display: list-item;'><a href='#'><span class='m'><input type='radio' class='fbol_ff' value=" + field.id + " family=" + field.family + "/></span>" + field.family + "</a></li>");

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dFour'></div>
```

Comment: @supermans, See code snippet, I have used JSON object in example

Answer (score 0):

Use the length of json in the loop.

```
generateFamily("a");

function generateFamily(objt) {
    result = $.getJSON("dta_text.json", function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var char = "a";
            char = "ln-" + char;
            for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(result).length; i++) {
                 $("#dFour").append("<li class=" + char + " style='display: list-item;'><a href='#'><span class='m'><input type='radio' class='fbol_ff' value=" + field[i].id + " family=" + field[i].family + "/></span>" + field[i].family + "</a></li>");
            }
        });
    });
}
```